# Error: Package "@ionic/angular-toolkit" has no builders defined. at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic

LLevo dias intentando solucionar pero aun sin resultados positivos asumia que era el angular.json cree otro proyecto y aun nada todo esto paso cuando fui actualizando el proyecto con el angular cli

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Actualizaste tu versión de los cli?

Comment:  hola! Podrías dejar el código del error en la pregunta así ayudas a que otros devs puedan buscar de mejor manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre Solucionarlo de esta forma espero a alguien le salve editando el ANGULAR.JSON

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).